# Liquid doesn't support generation of svg in Jekyll project

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I have a Jekyll project which is using svg images with the picture tag.
When I try to build the project the build process fails with the following error message:

```
Liquid Exception: No support for generating svg files in this environment. in publications.html  
bundler: failed to load command: jekyll (/home/<user>/repos/<project>/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/bin/jekyll)
```

This is the code snippet

```rb
{%  
  picture {{ site.baseurl_root }}{{ tool.icon }}  
%}
```

I already created a file in the _plugins folder, following [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13687032).
Unfortunately it didn't work for me.

Comment: I am not very familiar with liquid or jekyll but have you tried `{% include my_file.svg %}` ? As mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976183/with-jekyll-links-inside-svg-graphics-arent-working/29977737#29977737 and here: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/370#issuecomment-50948261 and here: https://davidensinger.com/2014/11/how-to-dynamically-include-svgs-inline-with-jekyll/? It also appears that there is a small gem for this as well [`jekyll-inline-svg`](https://github.com/sdumetz/jekyll-inline-svg)

Comment: @engineersmnky `include_relative` does the job. Thanks.